# how can i resize QLineEdit when it is used to be a editor?

Tags: windows, qt

```
QWidget* EditDelegate::createEditor(
  QWidget* parent,
  const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
  const QModelIndex& index) const
{
  QLineEdit* editor = NULL;
  if(index.isValid())
  {
    editor->resize(50,1000);  //this can not work in win7
  }
  return editor;
}
```

EditDelegate is subclass of QItemDelegate
what do you guys think this question?

Comment: Why are you trying to resize it? Normally Qt would be handling all of that depending on the view that is being used.

Comment: Can I ask why are you trying to set the editor to be 1000 pixels high?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you declare `QLineEdit` pointer you need to create an instance of the class

```
if(index->isValid()) {
  editor = new QLineEdit();
  editor->resize(50, 1000);
}
```

Comment: thanks all guys!  I have resolve this question .                   In QAbstractItemView,there's a system function  "indexWidget(...)" . haha,you know I can do it like following :                      QWidget* editor = indexWidget(m_indexCurrent);                   QLineEdit* eee = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);                eee->  "set what you loves"